# Esclarecimento arquietetura MVC em PHP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Boa tarde galera, estou iniciando com o php OO e com MVC, gostaria de saber se o trecho de código a baixo foge dos padrões, e se tem alguma melhoria para ser implementada.
Desde já agradeço a todos que colaborarem.

```
   <form method="post" action="getdata.php"> 
    <label> 
    Nome <input type="text" name="nome" /> 
    </label> 
    <label> 
    Email <input type="text" name="email" /> 
    </label> 
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" /> 
    </form>
```

classe PHP

```
<?php 

class getData{ 
 private $nome; 
 private $email; 

 public function getNome(){ 
 $this->nome = $_POST['nome']; 
 } 

 public function getEmail(){ 
 $this->email = $_POST['email']; 
 } 

 public function exibir(){ 
 echo $this->nome . ' <br /> ' . $this->email; 
 } 
 } 

 $getData = new getData(); 

 $getData->getNome(); 
 $getData->getEmail(); 
 $getData->exibir(); 

 ?>
```

Eu estou iniciando com o PHP agora mas a algum tempo já programo com Java, a questão do nome da classe e o pilar do encapsulamento quebrado eu percebi, este exemplo eu encontrei na net dando uma pesquisada rápida.
Eu achei estranho em um arquivo criar a classe e instancia-lo no mesmo arquivo. Se fosse em java faria da seguinte forma

```
public class ProcessaDados extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
          //recuperaria os dados 
          String nome = req.getParameter("nome");
          String email = req.getParameter("email");
         //criaria o Modelo e realizaria o restante da regra
    }
```

Comment: `get` geralmente é para extrair algum tipo de informação e não atribuir (`set`).

Comment: MVC não é tecnologia é maneira "de fazer as coisas" e o teu código **não tem nada "MVC"**. Note que OO e MVC **não definem qualidade** e organização, ajudam, mas se não souber o que esta fazendo então só piora. Um MVC pode ser construído sem OO, mas não é este o ponto, o que quero dizer é que se não tem motivos reais e necessários para usar não use, se é algo simples apenas algumas ifs e variaveis no PHP resolvem. Se quer usar algo "funcional" **e é** um projeto grande (com muitas pessoas) e talvez apresente certa complexidade então procure um framework já popular, não reinvente a roda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde amigo,

No mundo MVC, temos fundamentalmente 3 itens a se observar:

---

### Model

Sempre que você pensar em manipulação de dados, pense em model. Ele é responsável pela leitura e escrita de dados, e também de suas validações.

### View

Simples: a camada de interação com o usuário. Ela apenas faz a  exibição dos dados, sendo ela por meio de um html ou xml.

### Controller

O responsável por receber todas as requisições do usuário. Seus métodos chamados actions são responsáveis por uma página, controlando qual model usar e qual view será mostrado ao usuário.

---

Sabendo disso, e olhando para o código que você informou o primeiro trecho de código seria uma **view**.

arquivo_view.php:

```
<form method="post" action="usuario_controller.php"> 
    <label> 
        Nome <input type="text" name="nome" /> 
    </label> 
    <label> 
        Email <input type="text" name="email" /> 
    </label> 
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" /> 
</form>
```

Porém a seguir teríamos que receber o POST desse formulário em nosso **controller**, que decidirá qual **model** usar, e a seguir qual **view** exibir ao final.

Arquivo usuario_model.php

```
<?php
    class Usuario {
        private $nome;
        private $email;
        private $data_nascimento;

        public function getNome(){
            return $this->nome;
        }

        public function setNome($nome){
            $this->nome = $nome;
        }

        public function getEmail(){
            return $this->email;
        }

        public function setEmail($email){
            $this->nome = $email;
        }

        public function getDataNascimento(){
            return $this->data_nascimento;
        }

        public function setDataNascimento($data_nascimento){
            $this->data_nascimento= $data_nascimento;
        }

        public function exibir(){
            echo $this->nome . ' <br /> ' . $this->email . ' <br /> ' . $this->data_nascimento;
        }
    }
?>
```

Arquivo usuario_controller.php

```
<?php
    include('usuario_model.php');

    $usuario = new Usuario();
    $usuario->setNome($_POST['nome']);
    $usuario->setEmail($_POST['email']);
    $usuario->setDataNascimento($_POST['data_nascimento']);
    $usuario->exibir();
?>
```

A grosso modo, e de uma forma bem básica o que você fez dentro de um modelo MVC também bem básico, a ideia seria essa. Procure sempre desmembrar os arquivos de acordo com sua funcionalidade para manter um código **sustentável** e **limpo**.

Sobre os conceitos de POO, acredito que você tenha pecado em utilizar funções com nome **get** para alterar valor de uma propriedade de um objeto. Como eu fiz ali você deveria ter utilizado a nomenclatura **set**, e o get para retornar o valor já existente.

Artigos recomendados:

[MVC e PHP - Entendendo o padrão MVC na prática](https://www.webdevbr.com.br/mvc-e-php-entendendo-o-padrao-na-pratica-criando-um-framework-php)
[PHP Orientado a Objetos para Iniciantes](https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762)